# How to cook roast pork with a crackling wrap

Tags: pork

I bought a joint of pork from the market and they asked if I'd like them to put a crackling wrap on top - so obviously I said yes.  The crackling wrap seems to be a thin sheet of fat that she simply placed on top of the joint.

My question is - do I need to do anything different in the cooking process to cater for this, or just roast it as normal (with the crackling wrap on top)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lucky you! Not sure which cut of meat you have or what your normal cooking method is, but this crackling wrap can add a lot of flavor and moisture to your roast.  It`s great, especially with leaner cuts that can tend to be dry.

You want to season your roast as usual, but be sure to put seasoning between the wrap and the top of the roast (and on top of the wrap). You will want to cook the roast low and slow to your desired doneness.

The crackling wrap will act like a fat cap on top of the roast and slowly render the fat, essentially basting your roast as it cooks.

Rather than buy a pork or beef roast out of the case that has been trimmed all the way down, we usually ask the butcher to get us one out of the back that has not been trimmed. We then trim the bottom and leave the fat on top so that we can achieve this same result.